# How I can detect the digest authentication failure with libcurl?

Tags: c, libcurl

When we send a http message with:

```
res= curl_easy_perform(curl);
```

How to detect the authentication failure from libcur in case that the http message was sent with wrong login or password?

I checked the value of `res` for both success and failure and I found it = to 0

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`curl_easy_perform` will return `0` if the request went through successfully.

Bad authentication typically results in a 401 Unauthorized HTTP response code. However, cURL doesn't count that as a request error. An example of request error is `CURLE_URL_MALFORMAT`, which would be returned if your request URL was incorrectly formatted, which would mean the request didn't even hit the remote server.

Some may advise you to use `CURLOPT_FAILONERROR` to make `curl_easy_perform` fail if the response code is greater or equal to 400. However, the libcurl documentation expressly warns you about that:

> This method is not fail-safe and there are occasions where non-successful response codes will slip through, especially when authentication is involved (response codes 401 and 407).

The proper way to check for authentication errors would be to use `curl_easy_getinfo` to fetch the HTTP response code, e.g.:

```
CURLcode res = curl_easy_perform(curl);
long httpCode = 0;
curl_easy_getinfo(curl, CURLINFO_RESPONSE_CODE, &httpCode);
```